# How to unit test conditional render of deconstructed props?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test the existence of the `Typography` element from Material-UI when the `bio` prop is true. However, I'm receiving an error that the element is not being received. Please advise, thank you.

MyComponent.js

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const {
    classes,
    profile: { handle, createdAt, profileImage, bio, website, location}
  } = props;

  return (
    {bio && <Typography variant='body2'>{bio}</Typography>}
  )

  MyComponent.propTypes = {
    profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent)
```

MyComponent.test.js

```
describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  let shallow;
  let wrapper;

  const myProps = {
    profile: {
        bio: 'this is a bio'
    }
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    shallow = createShallow();
    wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...myProps} />);
  })

  it('should render a Typography element', () => {
    console.log(wrapper.debug(MyComponent));
    expect(wrapper.dive().find(Typography)).toHaveLength(1);
  })
})
```

Error

```
expect(received).toHaveLength(expected)

Expected length: 1
Received length: 0
Received object: {}

console.error node_modules/@material-ui/styles/mergeClasses/mergeClasses.js:36
Material-UI: the key `bio` provided to the classes prop is not implemented in MyComponent.
You can only override one of the following: paper,profile.
console.log src/components/MyComponent/MyComponent.test.js:36
<MyComponent classes={{...}} profile={{...}} />
```

Comment: 2 things I noticed... As per material doc, `shallow(<MyComponent {...myProps} />); ` should be inside `it` block.
Did you try logging MyComponent? `console.log(wrapper.debug())`

Comment: @soumyasunny thanks for the reply. I've attempted your solution but I'm sorry it did not work. I've updated my post with the `console.error`. Also, I'd like to keep `shallow(<MyComponent {...myProps} />);` inside the `beforeEach` and outside the `it` block as I will be adding more tests for this component. I receive the same `console.error` by placing it inside the `it` block so I left it inside the `beforeEach` instead.

Comment: Don't use MyComponent inside debug. It is just console.log(wrapper.debug()). Also, is it working if you pass `classes` in props?

Comment: @soumyasunny Ok sure, I've now removed `MyComponent` from inside debug and passed `classes` in props like this `const myProps = {profile: {}, classes: {}}`. We now only get this as an error. `expect(received).toHaveLength(expected) Expected length: 1 Received length: 0 Received object: {}`.